# Нужно ли ставить тире перед "словно"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Его рана выглядела плохо - словно рука побывала в кипящем масле.*

Я помню правило, которое говорит, что не надо ставить тире перед сравнительным союзом (словно, будто), но там было условие, что перед сравнительным союзом должно стоять сказуемое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире не надо было бы ставить в случае наподобие: *"Его рука словно побывала в кипящем масле"*.
Здесь же, как я понимаю, случай под [это](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109) правило:

> Тире ставится для подчеркивания, акцентирования поясняющих членов
> предложения, расположенных в конце предложения. Чаще всего это
> обстоятельство: *Это очень скверно, как я должен был писать — из-за
> куска хлеба* (Бун.)

Answer (score 1):

Тире ставится по [этому правилу (пункт 2, подпункт 6)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142), то есть, словами справочника Розенталя, из-за интонационного отделения главного предложения от придаточного.  Обычно между главным и придаточным произносится короткая пауза, но если эта пауза более длительная, чем стандартная, то ставится тире. Вот пара примеров из Розенталя:

> Вы спросите — зачем я пошёл на это?
> А вы уверены — нужно ли это?

Answer (score 1):

Если уж говорить о правилах Розенталя, то лучше вспомнить следующее. **Присоединительными** могут быть любые конструкции, в том числе предложения.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

Что касается постановки тире **в СПП при наличии паузы**, то это предложение не подходит под стандарт. Придаточное сравнительное должно выглядеть так:
*Его рука выглядела плохо, словно она побывала в кипящем масле.* В этом случае желательно поставить запятую, а не тире. У нас же в качестве предмета в одном случае говорится о ране, а в другом — о руке.

У Розенталя же приводятся примеры с придаточными изъяснительными, где тире отнюдь не редкость.

Поэтому лучше остановиться **на присоединительной** конструкции.

Comment: Не только изъяснительные. Там есть ещё уступительные, условные, временные. Очевидно, могут быть и другие. В этом составном предложении есть главное, придаточное, сравнительный придаточный союз ‟словно”. Плохость раны сравнивается с рукой, побывавшей в кипящем масле.

Comment: Ну если не очень понятно, то могу так объяснить.  У Розенталя в его примерах, можно и запятую поставить, это авторский выбор, а вот в заданном предложении возможно только тире. Значит, причина постановки тире другая. Я бы ее назвала структурным несоответствием.